# ListView Data Binding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On Login or Navigating to any Page, fetching data from API, I am using an extra button (Show Communities) to fetch my Fetch my Data. here is my code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:epolleasy.ViewModels;assembly=epolleasy"
         x:Class="epolleasy.Views.DpCommunities">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:DashboardViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>


<StackLayout>

    <Button Command="{Binding GetDashboard}" Text="Show Communities"/>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserDashboard.Com}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CommunityName}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CommunityUsers.Count}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FormsCommunity.Count}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

Here is **GetDashboard** Command in my ViewModel

```
public ICommand GetDashboard
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
             var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
             UserDashboard = await _apiServices.GetDashboard(accessToken);
        });
    }
```

}

Here is my **UserDashboard** in the same view model.

```
public Dashboard UserDashboard
    {
        get { return _userDashboard; }
        set
        {
            _userDashboard = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I want to get rid of that **extra button**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get your data in the OnAppearing method

```
void async override OnAppearing() 
{
   // call VM GetData method
}
```

Comment: yes, or just expose that same code as a public method

Comment: Not working, i guess i didnt get it correctly. Can you please write that OnAppearing() method bit more?

Comment: are you putting it in your page?  Did you verify that it's getting called?  Just saying "not working" is not very helpful information.

Comment: I didnt get your answer.

Comment: I asked you several questions, and you didn't respond to any of them.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from these small code snippets that you are provided and what I can conclude... you are binding your ListView to some `List` or `ObservableCollection`, and when Command is "triggered" (on button click) you are calling the WebApi.

To remove usage of the button: You can use that code where you are calling the web api and you can **put it inside of your ViewModel constructor**, so in that case you making it easy and Web Api will be called automatically on creating your ViewModel and your `List` or `ObservableCollection` will be populated, and if you are "respecting" the MVVM in the right way your `ListView` will be updated correctly with your data from api.

This is my opinion and this approach will work, question for community is: "**Is it a good practice to do like this?**"... But as I said this will work for you, and you will not have the need for that `Button`.

*P.S. Next time include all your classes that are relevant not just small methods, when you include all code we can see situation that you have and we can help you*